With OpenIddict options.UseOpenIddict() call in AddDbContext is necessary?
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    options.UseOpenIddict();
});

I want make this call but i get this error:
CS1061 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseOpenIddict' and no accessible extension method 'UseOpenIddict' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.10">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.AspNetCore" Version="5.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.Core" Version="5.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.Server" Version="5.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

It's like there's a package missing, but every guide says them. What could be the source of the error, or is this call no longer necessary?
Implementation of OpenIddict provider in ASP .NET8 API with EntityFrameworkCore.

You have to install OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore. Documentation: Entity Framework Core integration

@SvyatoslavDanyliv That hurt... :')
Thank you very much for your help!
